# WINAPI Read all access rights for a custom file or a folder

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, user-accounts

I have a task based on an algorithm to receive the access rights for a certain file or folder and I've tried to implement it but some parts don't seem to be clear.
What I've been asked for:

> 1) Use the function GetNamedSecurityInfo(), for example:
>   GetNamedSecurityInfo(path,SE_FILE_OBJECT,DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,NULL,
>   NULL,&a,NULL, &pSD)
>
> 2) Futher, use an SID to receive the rights: Use
>   these functions to receive the SID: GetAclInformation(), then GetAce().
>
> 3) Now you can use the LookupAccountSid() function and if is was
>   successfull, compare pACE->Mask with all the constants, for example
>   "GENERIC_ALL, GENERIC_READ, GENERIC_WRITE, GENERIC_EXECUTE for files
>   etc." displaying the access rights.

And how I tried to implement this algorithm: // First getting process SID

```
PSID g_pSID;
BOOL GetCurrentProcessSID()
{
    DWORD dwSize = 0, dwError, dwResult = 0;
    HANDLE hToken;

    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
    {
        printf("OpenProcessToken Error %u\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Call GetTokenInformation to get the buffer size.
    TOKEN_USER tU;
    if (!GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenUser, &tU, 0, &dwSize))
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
        if (dwError != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
        {
            std::cout << "GetTokenInformation failed, error " << dwError;
            CloseHandle(hToken);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    PTOKEN_OWNER to = (PTOKEN_OWNER)LocalAlloc(LPTR, dwSize);
    if (!to)
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "LocalAlloc failed, error " << dwError;
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        return 0;
    }

    if (!GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenOwner, to, dwSize, &dwSize))
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "GetTokenInformation failed, error " << dwError;
        LocalFree(to);
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        return 0;
    }

    g_pSID = to->Owner;
    return TRUE;
}
```

//Then I used the iteration through the ACL list:

```
std::stringstream g_TestSecurityResult;
void TestSecurity( wchar_t* path )
{
    g_TestSecurityResult = std::stringstream();
    GetCurrentProcessSID();
    PACL pDacl; 
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD;
    GetNamedSecurityInfoW(path, SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, &pDacl, NULL, &pSD);

    ACL_SIZE_INFORMATION aclSizeInfo = { sizeof(ACL) };

    BOOL fResult = GetAclInformation( pDacl, &aclSizeInfo, sizeof(ACL_SIZE_INFORMATION), ACL_INFORMATION_CLASS::AclSizeInformation );

    if (fResult)
    {
        for (DWORD dwIndex = 0; dwIndex < aclSizeInfo.AceCount; ++dwIndex)
        {
            LPVOID pTempAce = nullptr;

            fResult = ::GetAce(pDacl, dwIndex, &pTempAce);
            if (fResult)
            {
                PSID pSid = &((ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE*)pTempAce)->SidStart;

                if (EqualSid(pSid, &g_pSID))
                {
                    g_TestSecurityResult << "User: " << userNameFromSid(&g_pSID) << std::endl;
                    g_TestSecurityResult << "\tAccess mode: " << ((EXPLICIT_ACCESS*)pTempAce)->grfAccessMode << "\n";
                    g_TestSecurityResult << "\tAccess permissions: " << ((EXPLICIT_ACCESS*)pTempAce)->grfAccessPermissions << "\n";
                    g_TestSecurityResult << "\tInheritance: " << ((EXPLICIT_ACCESS*)pTempAce)->grfInheritance << "\n";
                    g_TestSecurityResult << std::endl;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                g_TestSecurityResult << "GetAce() failed." << GetLastError();
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        g_TestSecurityResult << "Error in GetAclInformation(): " << GetLastError();
    }
}

std::string userNameFromSid(PSID userSid)
{
    char buffName[MAX_BUFF_SIZE];
    DWORD buffNameSize = MAX_BUFF_SIZE;
    char buffDomain[MAX_BUFF_SIZE];
    DWORD buffDomainSize = MAX_BUFF_SIZE;
    SID_NAME_USE SidType;

    if (LookupAccountSid(NULL, userSid, buffName, &buffNameSize, buffDomain, &buffDomainSize, &SidType)) {
        return buffName;
    } else {
        DWORD dwResult = GetLastError();
        printf("GetTokenInformation Error %u\n", dwResult);
    }

    /*Here some code to print error in a Message box*/
    return "";
}
```

**The problem:** The code is working but at the line *if (EqualSid(pSid, &g_pSID))* debugger goes through and skips the SID that I've received from my process. In other words, I can't get any information from the ACL list, even though I'm running the process and Visual Studio under Administrator account (not using the "Run as Administrator", and I'll try it but still... The received SID is valid and I can get the name of the process owner using the above function. What could be something that I'm doing wrong here?

Code sources: 
https://gist.github.com/m4x1m1l14n/37f39c5d25855c2b1d3a6334851f7549
[How to get the logged-on user's SID in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366383/how-to-get-the-logged-on-users-sid-in-windows?rq=1)
[GetTokenInformation, TOKEN_OWNER, и LookupAccountSidA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37002790/gettokeninformation-token-owner-%D0%B8-lookupaccountsida)

Comment: why you not use `AccessCheck` ?

Comment: @RbMm  because I'm implementing an algorithm that was given by a university course so that it says "use this, and use that, and so on" as you can see, I'm now trying to observe AccessCheck() but still the original task was not about AccessCheck()

Comment: FYI, this assignment should be updated for at least UAC in Vista (2006). Access to a file may be limited by its `LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` in combination with the integrity level of the current security context (`TokenIntegrityLevel`) and its mandatory policy (`TokenMandatoryPolicy`). Also, the kernel `AccessCheck` (i.e. `SeAccessCheck`) in Windows 8+ supports Authz *conditional* ACEs (e.g. used extensively for UWP apps in "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps"), for which we may need a file's `ATTRIBUTE_SECURITY_INFORMATION` and `SCOPE_SECURITY_INFORMATION`.

Comment: Is this a typo, `&g_pSID`? Use `EqualSid(pSid, g_pSID)` instead of `EqualSid(pSid, &g_pSID)`.

Comment: @Rita Han - MSFT , thank you, I'm probably just forgotten to remove the ampersand from the previous version of my code where I tried to use SID variable instead of pSID pointer... And everything is working for now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @(Rita Han - MSFT) comment, I've forgotten to remove the ampersand mark from the pSID comparison

```
EqualSid(pSid, g_pSID);
```

instead of

```
EqualSid(pSid, &g_pSID);
```

And It's properly working for now

Comment: `(EXPLICIT_ACCESS*)pTempAce` is not proper. The structure of an ACE has nothing to do with an explicit-access record. Cast `pTempAce` as a `PACE_HEADER`, and skip all entries where `AceFlags` contains `INHERIT_ONLY_ACE`. Those entries do not apply to the current file/directory.

Comment: The loop needs to separately accumulate a granted-access mask and a denied-access mask. Skip an entry if it's not for the target SID or if it's inherit-only. Otherwise, if it's an allow entry, add the `Mask` rights to the granted-access mask that are not already in the denied-access mask. If it's a deny entry, add `Mask` rights to the denied-access mask that are not already in the granted-access mask. This allows explicit entries to override inherited entries, given that inherited entries are canonically ordered after explicit entries. At the end, the granted-access mask has the result.